# Explicit formula for a gauge transformation with winding number?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory

Does anyone know of an explicit expression for a gauge transformation, $\Omega:S^3\to G$, with a non-zero winding number (with $G=SU(n)$ say)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, as Mike has commented, you find a gauge transformation that winds in the SU(2) subgroup; and examples of such transformations are given in (2.37) of https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/gaugetheory/gt.pdf.

Answer (score 0):

All $SU(N)$'s have $SU(2)$ subgroups and  $SU(2)$'s group manifold is  $S^3$. So just map each point on $S^3$ to its corresponding point in any chosen  $SU(2)$.

Comment: That will have zero winding number no?

Comment: @dennis. No. It has $N=1/(24 \pi^2)\int_{S^3} (g^{-1}dg)^2= 1$.